Calling Process.Start works in WPF but NOT WinUI 3
Were trying to call Process.Start on a uri so it opens the default browser, the code works on WPF but not WinUI 3 as it gives the following exception:
An error occurred trying to start process [the big long authorizationRequest string is shown here...] with working directory 'C:\Windows\system32'. The system cannot find the file specified.
Referring to this answer I made sure the app runs as x64 but we still get the exception.
What modifications can be made to get this code working on WinUI3?
const string clientID = "581786658708-elflankerquo1a6vsckabbhn25hclla0.apps.googleusercontent.com";
const string clientSecret = "3f6NggMbPtrmIBpgx-MK2xXK";
const string authorizationEndpoint = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth";
const string tokenEndpoint = "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token";
const string userInfoEndpoint = "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo";

// Creates the OAuth 2.0 authorization request.
string authorizationRequest = string.Format("{0}?response_type=code&scope=openid%20profile&redirect_uri={1}&client_id={2}&state={3}&code_challenge={4}&code_challenge_method={5}",
    authorizationEndpoint,
    System.Uri.EscapeDataString(redirectURI),
    clientID,
    state,
    code_challenge,
    code_challenge_method);

// Opens request in the browser.
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(authorizationRequest);


I resolved it by calling LaunchUriAsync as oppose to Process.Start
await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri(authorizationRequest));
